# growth rate calculation with a loop

Tags: c++

So I was asked to solve this problem which I don't fully understand that's why I have difficulties starting with it since I'm still a beginner. here it is :

There are approximately 2.5 billion people on the Internet as of
January 2013. Facebook reached one billion users in October of 2012. In this exercise, you’ll
write a program to determine when Facebook will reach 2.5 billion people if it were to grow at
fixed monthly percentage rates of 2%, 3%, 4% or 5%.

As u see I should compute 4 times with different rate and I should each time using a for loop , get month and year when it reach 2.5 billion user . I was given this hint from another exercise to use inside the for loop but I didnt understand how to use it .

```
  amount =  pow ( 1.0 * rate , year )
```

now let say u fixed the border of loop `for ( int i = 1000000000 ; i <= 2500000000 ; here if I put ++i its not logical ! )`

then inside the loop its easier I think I'm going to count month let say we start at 10 ( which is October 2012 ) if we reach 25 that mean 10 + 15 which mean the date will be January 2014 but the prob is on how to make a cout statement to the user of those information u see? can u help me get the right structure ? thanks

Comment: You can do things like `i += some_number` in the spot where you normally do `i++`.

Comment: what do you mean by some_number ?? it should do a specific task is in it ??

Comment: Are you sure you need a for loop? A while loop seems to be called for here.

Comment: I was unable to structure my loop . I tried both but no positive result . I need to go from initial 1 billion and stop on 2.5 billions changing each time the rate . now the problem is how to get  month and year when it reaches 2.5 billions for each rate formula u see ?  we can use a formula such as m = m + m * 2 / 100 were we get new growth bu it should increment month if didnt reach 2.5 billions

Comment: Just a hint... stop thinking about years... your variable is the month... If you want to calculate years just devide the final months by 12... but thinking with years makes the problem more complicated... Every month multiply by 1.02 or 1.03 etc... and you have the months users

Comment: You can do i=pow(i, 1.05) or something

Comment: yes I know I should get year from month but I have a problem writing the structure of the loop any suggestions on how to structure the  loops ?? thanks

Comment: You can calculate this mathematically using logarithm. Did you take algebra in high school? Do you remember any of it?

Comment: are you sure that you are supposed to use a for loop? Did you already learn about a while loop?

Comment: the problem is with the structure and how to display things . I should probably do it differently something like that initial_growth = 1 billion then  final_growth = initial_growth + initial_growth* rate / 100 and then put a condition  while ( final_growth != 2500000000 ) it should keep adding what do u guys think ?

Comment: there is no reason to carry all that zeros along with your calculation, if you start with 1 billion and need to run till 2.5 billion then just use `double start = 1.0` and `double end = 2.5`

Comment: Yes I see tobi303 . any suggestions for me . Am I doing it the right way or should I think differently according to the problem ??

Comment: thx guys I finally found the solution . thx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved via using a **while** loop (instead of a for loop), like so:

```
#include <iostream>


double GrowthRatio = 1.05d; // Using 5% growth in this example.
double nUsers = 1000000000;
int MonthsElapsed = 0;

while((nUsers *= GrowthRatio) < 2500000000)
    MonthsElapsed++;

std::cout << MonthsElapsed;
```

Output:
`18`

Which means it took Facebook 18 months (from October 2012) to reach 2.5 billion users.